# RegExp: get word without word before it

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a file with lots of *"lore ipsum Bar lore ipsum"* and *"lorem ipsuem Foo Bar lorem ipsuem"*

How to get all occurrences of `Bar` without `Foo` via RegExp (ignore all "Foo Bar", pick "Bar")?

Something like:

`^(?!.*Foo). Bar*$`

??

Comment: So, it is JavaScript? What is your final goal? Get all matches or replace with something else? See https://regex101.com/r/mU9wC3/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew correct, JavaScript - need to replace all occurrences of  Bar with Foo Bar, leaving existing single Bar untouched.

Comment: I know how to do it in 3 steps (without RegExp). Just want to do it WITH RegExp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^(?!.*Foo). Bar*$` pattern matchersd a string that doers not have a `Foo` somewhere inside, and that starts with any char but a newline, followed with a space and then ends with `Ba` + zero or more `r`s. I doubt you need this regex in real life.

You can do it with a callback method inside a `replace` method using a known regex trick to match what you do not need first, and then match and capture what you need.

See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/fV6iV1/1):

```
\bFoo Bar\b|(\bBar\b)
^--match--^ ^-capture-^
```

I wrapped the words with word boundaries, you might discard them if you do not have word chars at the start/end of the strings you search.

```js
var re = /\bFoo Bar\b|(\bBar\b)/g;    // Declare the regex
var str = 'lore ipsum Bar lore ipsum\nlorem ipsuem Foo Bar lorem ipsuem';
var subst = '<b>Foo Bar</b>';         // A sample substitution
var result = str.replace(re, function($0, $1) {  // Use the anonymous method
  return $1 ? subst : $0;           // If Group 1 matches, use a subst, else, reinsert the match back
});
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```